# TypeScript/React : "Parsing error: Unexpected token"

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm facing those parsing errors:

[image]

I'm using **Typescript 4.1.3**, with **React 17**, created with `create-react-app`.

I couldn't find any relevant help on Google.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is a chance the first undescore is prepended with some invisible unicode codepoint. I'd recommend you remove the whole line and retype it manually from scratch.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried to type it again, but was not successful. Another issue I had was when I wanted to use the non-null assertion operator (!), which resulted in a parsing error too.